# Dlib "Error serializing object"

Tags: dlib

What can cause the following error when serializing an object in dlib?

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type dlib::serialization_error: Error serializing object of type long while serializing dlib::matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory to which you write the serialization file does not exist.